M 2.4.7 - Opensearch 2.13 vs. Elasticsearch 8.5
What should be chosen for a Magento 2.4.7 store with 25,000 visual SKUs?
Should we go for Opensearch 2.13 or Elasticsearch 8.5? Which one will give us the best performance?
As far as we can see,
There are the following issues with Elasticsearch 8 since they have disabled sorting and aggregation in the _id field by default for performance reasons, 
this functionality was deprecated in ES 7.6. 
You can re-enable it by updating the dynamic cluster setting: indices.id_field_data.enabled

@Jesper Brejning
Hey,
This will help you to choose which search engine you have to use for magento 2.4.7,
https://pureinsights.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Elasticsearch-vs-OpenSearch-Business-Decision-Tree-1.pdf
Thank You!
